# What part of the GWT application is compiled into JavaScript?

Tags: java, gwt

GWT-compiler converts into JavaScript always only those classes which are in the package **client**? Or it can be configured in other way? How do I specify for GWT client-side code and server-side code?

I'm sorry if this question is naive. I'm novice in GWT. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is configured in your module file (.gwt.xml).

The `<source>` tags indicate which packages should be converted to JS. The "path" value is relative to your module.

You can change them to the following, for example:

```
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
<source path='mysubpackage' />
```

Answer (score 2):

And if no `<source>` tags is defined in the module file, the client subpackage is implicitly added to the source path as if `<source path="client" />` had been found in it. This default helps keep module file compact for standard project layouts.